# How to Trotterize a CNOT gate?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, trotterization

I came across a paper that said that they Trotterized a CNOT gate into 4 blocks of CU gates where the CU gate parameters are specified. This was all done on Qiskit. How does this Trotterization actually work? How do I perform it mathematically? Where is an actual proof that this Trotterization is equivalent to the CNOT gate itself. I have attached an image of the Trotterized CNOT gate if it is of any help. Thanks!

[image: Trotterized CNOT gate]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please provide a link to the paper you mentioned?

Comment: Hi @MartinVesely. I don't have the link to said paper anymore.